# Implementing RTMFP client in C

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, rtmfp

I am want to develop a client in C which uses RTMFP to communicate with Flash palyer for streaming video. I couldnt get much information on whether it is possible. I have looked into Cumulus project but i am not getting much insight into RTMFP specification.

If there is a workaround like writting a C wrapper around flex code is also fine. But i dont know if it is possible.

Any suggestion would be of great help.

Thanks.
Regards,
Jeeva

Comment: how are you going to connect to the flashplayer?

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the Flash OCX inside a C application and communicate with it, although I don't know if that would fulfill all your needs. I know multicast is possible without the need of a RTMFP server, but I don't know if that allows streaming video?

Sadly the RTMFP protocol uses a proprietary format which is not public and not fully known AFAIK, you can get some info here:

http://code.google.com/p/blue5/wiki/RTMPFPSpecs

But I don't know how valid it is.

Anyway, if you only want to stream video, and don't need any of the advantages of the RTMFP protocol, you could use RTMP with Red5, but maybe you already thought of it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that **Adobe has finally published the RTMFP specifications**.

See here:

http://blogs.adobe.com/standards/2014/04/17/adobes-rtmfp-profile-for-flash-communication-released

and here:

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-thornburgh-rtmfp-flash-07